How do I edit Redis connection string without actually being able to go to the admin?
I have a sitefinity instance set up in Azure App Service. I have a problem with the Redis connection string.
When I navigate to /Sitefinity to get to the admin portal, I'm getting this error.
Connection with Redis could not be established. Check the connection string and try again.

at
Telerik.Sitefinity.LoadBalancing.RedisSystemMessageSender.StartRedisReceiver()
at Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.SetupNLBComunication()
at Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.Initialize() at
Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.RegisterRoutes() at
Telerik.Sitefinity.Abstractions.Bootstrapper.Bootstrap() at
Telerik.Sitefinity.Web.SitefinityHttpModule.<>c.b__4_0(Object
ctx)

To fix this I need to go into the admin portal and change my Redis setting, but I can't get into the admin portal without fixing the Redis connection string.
How I fix my site?


Start here maybe? https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/database-storage-of-configurations - or if I've misunderstood the product: you'd need to search for that specifically

The value of the redis connection string is stored either in the file system, under App_Data / Sitefinity / Configuration / SystemConfig.config
or in the database, where you can use this query to get it:
select * from sf_xml_config_items
where path = 'SystemConfig.config'

After you find and update it, make sure to restart the site.

I had a look at the database, but the xml doesn't have the redis connection string there. The systemConfig just has an element called typeImplementationsMapping with a bunch of references to some classes. I had a look at some of the other rows inside that table and they don't seem to have it either

i just realised it's actually in the systemconfig.config file - in the file system. Ok did not realise sitefinity phyiscally writes the file to the file system
